# load a dynamic library from elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need to use some native code and I would like to try elisp as a scripting language. 
Is it possible to call native functions which are implemented in dynamic library (dll in windows)? Or the only possibility to do it is to implement native code, wrap it with DEFUN (...) macros and recompile emacs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can not dynamically load a library with Emacs Lisp code.  To work around this people usually call out to an external program (process) and control it by sending commands to it and reading its output.

You can look at slime, tramp, gnuserv, movemail and some other similar hacks for examples.

Answer (score 6):

[GNU Emacs 23](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) has [D-BUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-BUS) support.  While primarily a Unix thing, D-BUS is supported on Windows and provides an IPC system for user-level applications.

You could probably build what you want with that.

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible to load complied code as modules as of Emacs 25.1. See the [Dynamic Modules](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Writing-Dynamic-Modules.html) and [Writing Dynamic Modules](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Writing-Dynamic-Modules.html) sections in the manual for more details.

Essentially, you need to use some of the items in the `emacs-module.h` header file to initialize the module and create suitable wrappers around the C objects so that Emacs understands them. You compile this code as part of the module that you want to load; none of the foreign function definitions can occur inside of elisp code.

Answer (score 0):

This feature exists only in SXEmacs, that doesn't has support for Windows, but in Unixes it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `emacs` in terminal and windowed on Linux using `IELM REPL`:

Launch repl with: `M-x ielm`

In repl run `(load "<path_to_lisp_source>")`

Now you should be able to run any functions or access data from this loaded source.