# How can I call Windows API functions using emacs lisp?

Tags: windows, api, emacs, lisp

I want to call some Windows API functions to manipulate Windows Input Method Editor to make my Emacs an IME-aware application. How can I call Windows API functions using Emacs lisp?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you really want to do it? Cannot you specify the input method from emacs itself (e.g. using quail)? I usually use emacs with standard English keyboard so that all the standard emacs chords work.

Comment: @choroba, thank you. Because the built-in input method of Emacs is hard to use, so most of Chinese Emacs users use the native IME of the operating system. I have solved this problem by adding some functions to w32fns.c of Emacs and then calling them from elisp. GUN Emacs lacks the **FFI** (foreign function interface), so I cannot call Windows API functions from Emacs lisp directly. Thank you again.

Comment: So you have resolved this? You should describe your solution in an answer for others to see (including an example would be good), and then mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe its possible to directly call native code from emacs; the best you'll be able to achieve is to proxy calls to the Windows API through another process, and communicate with it through IPC

Check this stackoverflow question:
[load a dynamic library from elisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545216/load-a-dynamic-library-from-elisp)

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe need a proxy interface, but use [w32-send-sys-command](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WThirtyTwoSendSysCommand) can do little things,
code 61776 can send hotkey maybe worth a try